# How to record browse times of an article?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2.
How to record browse times of an article?
Like *stackoverflow.com*'s browse times,
when I refresh,times will not vary,
how to do it?

Comment: use a middleware. check if some variable is set in the session. If not, add the variable and count it as a view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using databse I would suggest to build new table with two columns (article_id, views):

```
CREATE TABLE `stats_articles` (
`article_id` INT NOT NULL,
`views` INT DEFAULT 0
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

> article_id should be foreign key linking to id column in you article table

Then in the place where you displaying your article you should execute sql which will increase a value `views` in your `stats_articles` table:

```
INSERT INTO `stats_articles` SET views=1 WHERE article_id=[ARTICLE_ID] ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=views+1;
```

This query is trying to insert new record into `stats_articles` with `views=1` or if it's existing already it will increase `views` value.

Right now you need to decide if you want to count each hit to the article or  limit to by cookies or sessions.

To do that, before  you increase db value check if user has already seen this article. Something like this pseudocode:

```
if (!cookie or seession for this [article_id] not exists) { // User see this article for a first time
   increase db value
} // if yes, do nothing
```